# R language: a field of two possible types in reference classes?

Tags: r

I am learning the OOP programming with R, in particular with reference classes.

If I have a class, e.g.

```
myclass <- setRefClass(class="myclass", fields=list(x="numeric"));
```

I know that if I do not want to set any class for x, I can just type fields=list(x="ANY"). But what if
I want to allow x to be of two possible classes, e.g. "numeric" or "logical". The "numeric" and "logical" classes  do not inherit from each other, so setting the one and passing the other class results in an error.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setClassUnion` like this:

```
setClassUnion("NumOrLog", c("numeric", "logical"))
myclass <- setRefClass("myclass", fields=list(x="NumOrLog"))

# test
myclass(x = 12) # ok
myclass(x = TRUE) # ok
myclass(x = "X") # bad
```

Note that it is not necessary to suffix R statements with a semi-colon.

Comment: Practically, I'd recommend staying away from class unions, and just using type "ANY". The less you use advanced S4 features, the more likely you code is to work in a wide variety of situations.

Comment: Thank You very much, Mr Grothendieck. This worked. But what if I want to make a class union of the classes "integer" and "difftime"? I cannot understand where the error comes from the following example: setClassUnion(name="intDifftime", members=c("integer", "difftime")); Class "difftime" is defined in the base package, but setClassUnion complains?

Comment: `"difftime"` is S3, not S4.  Issue `setOldClass("difftime") first to let the S4 system know about it.
`

Comment: Thank You very much, Mr Grothendieck, this was very helpful!